# how to deal with hex values higher than 7FF... 64 bits and uint64_t type

Tags: c++, hex, uint64

I am working with 64bit hex strings and, when I want to have the number in uint64_t, if the number is higher than 7f... it will not convert the number correct. 
Since I'm not english, i think i can show the problem better with a piece of code:

```
   void testing()
   {
      std::string str = "cba321456789654a";
      uint64_t res = std::strtol(str.c_str(), NULL, 16);
      cout << "RESULT " << std::hex << res << endl;
   }
```

And the result I'm getting is:

```
RESULT 7fffffffffffffff
```

Do I have to change the type of my variables to a bigger int? Or there is a way to solve this problem using uit64_t?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're dealing with unsigned, but are using a string-to-signed conversion routine.  And it's not converting to the correct type.  strtol converts to a  32-bits long.

```
 uint64_t res = std::strtol(str.c_str(), NULL, 16);
```

Should read

```
 uint64_t res = std::strtoull(str.c_str(), NULL, 16);
```

Here's a link to c++ string-to-int conversion routines documentation:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtoul

Answer (score 1):

(Talking about C, because I don't know much about C++. But I assume it still applies to C++.)

[`strtol()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol) returns an `int` (which btw isn't 64 bit wide on all platforms). So the domain is (assuming a 64 bit wide `int`) [`INT_MIN`, `INT_MAX`] = [-0x8000000000000000, 0x7fffffffffffffff] and so 0xcba321456789654a cannot be returned.

In POSIX and C99 there is a function [`strtoull()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtoull) that should do want you want, i.e. return an unsigned type.

Another alternative is

```
sscanf("cba321456789654a", "%llx", &res);
```

.